# Structure copy Vs Members copy (Time efficient)

Tags: c, performance, structure

We know that we can copy one structure to another directly by assignment.

```
struct STR
{
   int a;
   int b;
};
struct STR s1 = {4, 5};
struct STR s2;
```

Method 1:

```
s2 = s1;
```

will assign s1 to s2.

Method 2:

```
s2.a = s1.a;
s2.b = s1.b;
```

In terms of time efficiency, which method is the faster one? Or both would take same time for the operation. Consider in the aspects of big structure in data handling!

Comment: Method 1 is most likely more efficient, because usually is boils down to calling the `memcpy` function which is usually highly optimized for the platform. Other advantage of method 1: if you add a struct member, you don't need to change your copying code.

Comment: Let's ask an optimizing compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/FRUt1a

Comment: The difference is probably negligible. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: I just noticed with link from @StoryTeller: If a third element is adde to the struct which is of another type (float), the disassembly is different. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

Basically you cannot tell that, because it depends on the compiler, the target architecture, etc...

However, with modern C compilers, with optimization enabled they will be usually the same. For example, recent GCC on x86-64 generates exactly the same code for the two:

```
void a1()
{
  s2 = s1;
}

void a2()
{
  s2.a = s1.a;
  s2.b = s1.b;
}
```

Produces:

```
a1():
mov rax, QWORD PTR s1[rip] 
mov QWORD PTR s2[rip], rax
ret

a2():
mov rax, QWORD PTR s1[rip]
mov QWORD PTR s2[rip], rax
ret
```

Comment: ... what everybody (including me) forgot to mention, it also depends highly on the actual content of the struct. Add `int c[100];` to the struct and the produced code will be completely different. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/gZeG73